# Where is KVM guest configuration (xml) located in proxmox?

Tags: virtualization, configuration, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I wanted to check if my Proxmox instance uses LVM for KVM guests to achieve better performance

so Where is KVM guest configuration (xml) located in proxmox?

Answer (score 3):

The configuration files for guests is located at `/etc/pve/qemu-server`

Comment: +1 Thanks, but is there any KVM XML file for guests? because I think these files belongs to Proxmox itself.

Comment: There is no such thing as KVM XML file. There exist libvirt XML files, but not KVM.

Comment: Thank you, can you locate those XML files please?

Comment: There is no XML config for proxmox. All the configs are at /etc/pve/nodes/guest-name/qemu-server and they are .conf not xml :)